# Skin url, Base url in product description in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, base-url

How can i get the base url, skin url on paroduct description in magento admin panel?

Can i use this :

```
{{store url=""}}

{{skin url=''}}
```

for getting the url

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base URL in description field:

`This is <a href="{{store url="some-link"}}">Some Link</a>.`

Skin URL in description field:

`This is <a href="{{skin url="images/test.jpg"}}">Some Link</a>.`

Use the form without WYSIWYG editor (plain mode).

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `<p><a href="{{skin url}}images/btn_remove.gif">THis is the link</a></p>`

OR 
`<p><a href="{{skin url=images/btn_remove.gif}}">THis is the link</a></p>`
both work.

"skin url" etc. are magento's default variables for blocks

http://www.webdosh.net/2011/04/magento-get-skin-url-get-media-url-get.html